# QR code scanner for ionic project for auto filling the details

Tags: ionic-framework

Iam newbie to ionic and creating a basic mobile app after learning ionic online.

I had created a customer details form page where customers need to enter their details like, name, gender, dob, city etc.

Instead of manually entering the entering the details,  I want to put QR Scanner in the page so that when Aadhaar or any other barcode details saver QR code gets scanned the customer details needs to gets filled automatically.

Below is the code

```
    <ion-content>
    <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >Full Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >DOB</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >Gender</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >Address</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >State</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >District</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >City</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="floating" >Postal Code</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

I tried installing the ionic qr scanner plugins

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-qrscanner
 npm install @ionic-native/qr-scanner
```

But no idea how to proceed further. Please help me on this, i got struct on this from last 10 days
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my code for scanning QR codes (Ionic 4)
To be honest, I like the barcode-scanner way more than the qr code scanner and basically the outcome is the same.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/barcode-scanner

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { Platform, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { DatabaseService} from '../../providers/database/database.service';
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  current:any;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private router: Router,
    public db: DatabaseService,
    public barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner,
    private alertController: AlertController
  )
  {}
  scan()
  {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
      if(barcodeData.cancelled)
      {
        return
      }
      this.db.checkQRCode(barcodeData.text)
      .then(doc => {
      })
     }).catch(err => {
         console.log('Error', err);
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: hi @RobrechtVM, thank you for your answer. I tried the code but it's not working for me. Ii created a barcode code scan button in home page and signup form. Here is the project downloadable link: we.tl/t-USjvQmScDU please help me on this thank you